# Register Receiver to action Download Fail

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any action for Downloading fail like action **DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE** , I want to catch action fail for downloading

Comment: i think you should set listener onchanged for [status_failed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_FAILED)

Comment: the action that are supported to download manger are ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE , ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED , ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS I need to know if there is away to detect other actions like DOWNLOAD_FAIL I have already tried status_failed but the action are un detected except after ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE

Comment: it doesn't have action like what you want. you should check on status_failed yourself.